# Converting latitude and longitude to Declination and Right ascension and vice versa

Tags: python, astronomy

Is there any module that can do the conversion of `latitude` and `longitude` to `Declination` and `Right ascension` and vice versa. i have searched and could not find one that does this straight away.

Comment: Have you looked at astropy? https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/

Comment: @usernumber can you pls give me an example, as i dont find any direct example for my question

Comment: Well, you can't do the conversion straight away with just latitude and longitude. You also need date and time. You would have to use an astropy.coordiantes.EarthLocation and an astropy.time.Time.